# PostgreSQL Manipulating Values Using Column Indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a rather odd problem, that I cannot find a solution to implement.

I have a table to reformat, like below:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 | Col_5 | Col_6 | Formula |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| x     | x     | x     | x     | x     | x     |         |
|       | y     |       | y     | y     | y     |       4 |
|       | z     | z     | z     | z     |       |       2 |
| t     | t     | t     | t     | t     | t     |       5 |
| m     | m     | m     |       |       |       |       5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

x,y,z and t are being numeric values, and it is given that in each row, this values are either exactly same or blank. And in another column, I am given the column index to manipulate.

Then, in a view, I need to convert this table to something like below:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| Col_1 | Col_2 | Col_3 | Col_4 | Col_5 | Col_6 | Formula |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
| x     | x     | x     | x     | x     | x     |         |
|       |       |       | 2*y   | y     | y     |       4 |
|       | z     | z     | z     | z     |       |       2 |
|       |       |       |       | 5*t   | t     |       5 |
|       |       |       |       | 3*m   |       |       5 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+---------+
```

To say in words, I need to delete (or replace with 0, because values shouldn't be included to column sums ) the values of columns until the index specified by formula column, then add sum of this deleted values to the specified index.
For example in last row, columns 1-5 are deleted and added to column 5.

columns are literally named as col_1 etc. so even string operations are possible but I am not sure if it is a good way to solve this problem.

I don't know how to handle this problem at all so any help appreciated.
Thank you very very much in advance.

Comment: I think you have the wrong data structure for your data.  These values should probably be in separate rows rather than columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff agreed. although this looks like a homework question.  I doubt re-defining the question is an option.

Comment: The data is already here for the company I work, so altering the table is not an option here. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `CASE` expressions, that either return `NULL`, the sum of the previous fields and the current one multiplied by `formula` or the original column value depending on `formula`.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN formula < 1 THEN
           NULL
         WHEN formula = 1 THEN
           (coalesce(col_1, 0)) * formula
         ELSE
           col_1
       END col_1,
       CASE
         WHEN formula < 2 THEN
           NULL
         WHEN formula = 2 THEN
           (coalesce(col_1, 0)
            + coalesce(col_2, 0)) * formula
         ELSE
           col_2
       END col_2,
       ...
       CASE
         WHEN formula < 6 THEN
           NULL
         WHEN formula = 6 THEN
           (coalesce(col_1, 0)
            + coalesce(col_2, 0)
            + coalesce(col_3, 0)
            + coalesce(col_4, 0)
            + coalesce(col_5, 0)
            + coalesce(col_6, 0)) * formula
         ELSE
           col_6
       END col_6,
       formula
       FROM elbat;
```

(Note: For `col_1` this can be simplified, but like it stands it emphasizes the pattern more.)

Comment: Actually I was working on a plpgsql function, but got stuck so asked the question here. even though this is a longer and head-forward solution, it is doing the same thing and doing the trick. Thank you very much, it is been very helpful.